# Cf application in Bluemix - install dependency package

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, installation-package

I have a Spring Boot application deployed as a Cloud Foundry app on Bluemix. Unfortunately the core of this app depends on an external program (e.g. `abc`) which can be easily installed using `apt-get install abc` on a desktop environment. 
Is there any way to install such a dependency in a cloud foundry environment?

Many thanks for your support

Luca

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar challenge with R and am using a soon-to-be-discontinued [git repo](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt) which uses apt-get options to allow you to redirect your install into folders/directories where you have write authority during the staging process. You'll have to update your paths to ensure that you can access the installed code. The install process is multi-step,

- define the alternate path for apt
- define the path for your installation
- update apt
- use apt-get install ... to download the necessary packages and associated dependencies
- use dpkg to install the downloaded packages

Comment: Hi bob, thank you very much for your answer. So basically I have to fork this project and modify it for the usage with the Java build pack. I'll give a try and report my findings. Thanks again

Comment: @luca - How did your fork go?